# How to delete automated cluster from DataBricks?

Tags: azure, databricks, azure-databricks

Accidentally I have created automated cluster on Azure DataBricks. Is there any way do delete it?
I want to delete only one of them.[image]

Comment: Glad to know that your issue has resolved. You can accept it as answer( click on the check mark beside the answer to toggle it from greyed out to filled in.). This can be beneficial to other community members. Thank you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have deleted this with an api call from the [documentation](https://docs.databricks.com/dev-tools/api/latest/clusters.html#create-a-job-using-a-policy-with-the-api)
With url this kind of url:
https://westeurope.azuredatabricks.net/api/2.0/clusters/permanent-delete

It is important to give cluster id in body (you can find it in Advanced options -> tags and as authorized token use token generated from DataBricks portal.

Comment: Hi @Jack, Glad to know that your issue has resolved. You can accept it as answer( click on the check mark beside the answer to toggle it from greyed out to filled in.). This can be beneficial to other community members. Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

**Note:** The Azure Databricks job scheduler creates an **automated cluster** when you run a job on a new automated cluster and **terminates the cluster when the job is complete**.

> Here are the steps to delete the job created by automated clusters from Azure Databricks:

**Step1:** Select the Automated cluster which you want to delete.

[image]

**Step2:** Click on Go To Job Run

[image]

**Steo3:** Click on Delete

[image: ![enter image description here]

[image]

**[image: Complimentary Gif:]**

Comment: It does deletes jobs but does not delete cluster.

Comment: The Azure Databricks job scheduler creates an automated cluster when you run a job on a new automated cluster and terminates the cluster when the job is complete.